# Automation on iOS not triggering when connected to WiFi

Tags: shortcuts-app, ios

I have set automation on my iPhone to turn on DND when it connects to work WiFi, however, the automation doesn’t work.

Does anyone know why this wouldn’t work?

Here’s a screenshot of rule:
[image: Automation screenshot]

Comment: Did u set Do not Disturb On until your turned off ??

Comment: I’ve set it to “Until I leave”, does it affect how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/enable-or-disable-a-personal-automation-apd602971e63/ios, an automation based on Wi Fi cannot run automatically. You will get a notification asking if you want to run the automation. You then have to press Run.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn’t aware of this. Wish they would change that, things could be much easier to manage as I wouldn’t need to start automation with tap on notification.